# Error when using Model.save() to MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, schema, ejs

The issue that I am having is this:

I have two Schemas, one is a User, and the other is a Message.

Now, when I try to post  a message from one User to another, a message.id is created, however the text for the message and the author are not saving.

Here are my Schemas

```
var mongoose = require("mongoose");

var messageSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    text: { type: String },
    author: {
        id: {
            type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: "User"
        },
        name: { type: String }
    }
});

module.exports = mongoose.model("Message", messageSchema);
```

And User

```
var mongoose = require("mongoose");
var passportLocalMongoose = require("passport-local-mongoose");
var uniqueValidator = require('mongoose-unique-validator');

var UserSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    username: { type: String, required: true, unique: true },
    password: { type: String, required: true },
    first_name: { type: String, required: true },
    middle_initial: { type: String, required: true },
    last_name: { type: String, required: true },
    phone: { type: Number, required: true },
    address: { type: String, required: true },
    email: { type: String, required: true, unique: true },
    isManager: Boolean,
    isSysAdmin: Boolean,
    points_accrued: Number,
    id: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: "User"
    },
    messages: [
        {
            type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: "Message"
        }
    ]
});

UserSchema.plugin(passportLocalMongoose);
UserSchema.plugin(uniqueValidator);

module.exports = mongoose.model("User", UserSchema);
```

And Lastly here is my route

```
var express    = require("express"),
    router     = express.Router({ mergeParams: true }),
    User       = require("../models/user"),
    Message    = require("../models/message"),
    middleware = require("../middleware");

//INDEX SHOW USER INFO
router.get("/", middleware.isLoggedIn, function (req, res) {
    res.render("users/index");
});

// Gets messages for regular Employees, not Admins
router.get("/messages", middleware.isLoggedIn, function (req, res) {
    User.find({}, function (err, allUsers) {
        if (err) {
            console.log("Error Occured");
            console.log(err);
        } else {
            res.render("users/messages", { users: allUsers });
        }
    })
});

//================//
// POST A MESSAGE //
//================//

router.post("/messages", middleware.isLoggedIn, function (req, res) {
    User.findByUsername(req.body.reciever, function (err, foundUser) {
        if(err){
            console.log(err, "Could Not Find User");
            res.redirect("back");
        } else {
            console.log("User Found...");
            console.log(foundUser);
            Message.create(req.body.newMessage, function (err, newMessage) {
                if(err){
                    req.flash("error", "Whoops! Something went wrong...");
                    console.log(err);
                    res.redirect("/users/messages");
                } else {
                    newMessage.author.id = req.user._id;
                    newMessage.author.name = req.user.first_name + " " + req.user.middle_initial + " " + req.user.last_name;
                    newMessage.save();
                    // console.log(message.text);
                    foundUser.messages.push(newMessage);
                    foundUser.save();
                    req.flash("success", "Message Sent!");
                    res.redirect("/users/messages");
                }
            });
        }
    });
});


module.exports = router;
```

Now when I try to use <%= message.text %> I receive nothing, and when I try to console.log(message.text) in my ejs file I get undefined. When I try <%= message %> I get the ID for the message. Lastly, in my route, I can console.log(req.body.newMessage) and so on and it does comeback with the data. However when I try something like console.log(foundUser.messages[0].text) I get undefined even though I just used .save() on the Message and foundUser. I am really confused and if anyone can shine light on this that would be super helpful. I have tried pretty much everything that I could. Thanks!

UPDATE!!!!!!!

As it turns out, the Schema is correctly saving, however my issue still remains that I cannot view anything but the ID for the message. Here is that the data Object looks like:

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "5b26c60f25d6c9248c91b5ee"
    },
    "text": "hey",
    "__v": 0,
    "author": {
        "id": {
            "$oid": "5b25b6c25813b101b4887dec"
        },
        "name": "Scott W Selke"
    }
}
```

Comment: You haven't populate your messages in find query and also your `.save()` will not work here you need to use [`$push`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/push/) instead to update an array inside mongodb

Comment: Which find query would I populate the messages in? And how exactly would I use $push? If you could show me I would be super thankful;